# Do a pairwise comparison of each element in two sets and return a top 3 ranklist

Tags: python, python-2.x

Given two sets, how do I perform a pairwise comparison of each element in one set with each element of the other set.

I would like to get top 3 results for each element in the initial set.\

Is there a faster way to solve the task. I am looking for a more pythonic way of doing the task.

```
set1 = set([str(item) for item in range(100)])   # Pls. note originally set contains strings
set2 = set([str(item) for item in range(50,150)]) # set([str(item) for item in range(50,100)])

for item in set1:
  max = [-1,-1,-1]
  for stuff in set2:
    val = magicComp(item,stuff)
    if val > max[0]:
        max[2] = max[1]
        max[1] = max[0]
        max[0] = val
    elif val > max[1]:
        max[2] = max[1]
        max[1] = val
    elif val > max[2]:
        max[2] = val
```

Comment: So the value of an item in `set1` is defined by the maximum value of `magicComp(item1, item2)` for any item in `set2`?

Comment: The sets contain strings, as written in comments. I was just producing a minimally reproducible code. @dhke

Comment: What does "get top 3 results for each element in the initial set" mean?

Comment: For each element in set1, I need to get top 3 elements in set2, as per value returned by magicComp method @laike9m

Comment: You mean top 3 results of function `magicComp` with argument from set2?

Comment: Ah, so for each `item1` you want the first three elements of `set2` sorted by the return value from `magicComp(item1, item2)`?

Comment: @laike9m - yes top 3 results from set2, for every element in set1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer's not bad, it's better than sorting the array on each iteration, but it's still O(N^2).

Since you know the array indices that you want, you can use the [quickselect](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quickselect_algorithm#Python) algorithm to find indices 0,1,2 based on the magicComp function in O(log n) time.   This'll reduce your run-time to O(n*log n)

Based on the code in that link, your code would look something like:

```
results = {}
ls2 = list(set2)
for el in set1:
    results[el] = [select(ls2, ii) for ii in [0,1,2]]
```

Comment: Did you want to re-use `ls2`? Because afaik you could

Comment: Whoops, I had that in there from my first revision, fixing.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to be really pythonic, something like

```
from functools import partial

most_valueable = {
    item1: sorted(set2, key=partial(magicComp, item1), reverse=True)[0:3]
    for item1 in set1
}
```

should do the trick. This is still O(n² ln n), however, since we need to re-sort the second set for every item.

Answer (score 1):

Ehmmm, faster way. Your original version is of time complexity `O(3n)` for each inner iteration.

Below is faster with time complexity `O(nlg3)`.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

q = PriorityQueue(maxsize=3)
for item in set1:
    map(q.put, (-1 * magicComp(item,stuff) for stuff in set2))
    max = []
    while not q.empty():
        max.append(-1 * q.get())
```

Comment: This is probably just a heap sort on each iteration, so it'll be O(n*log n) for each element in set 1, or O(n^2 * log n) overall.

Comment: @gct **You're wrong. Heap's size is always 3, so it's `O(nlg3)` not `O(nlgn)`.**

Comment: Ah I see, I missed the max size.  Still, you'll be O(n*log 3) for the heap and then doing it for each element makes it O(n^2*log 3)